# Programmatic Login with remote realm authentication example

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-3

I'm trying to find an example of a standalone app (out of a JavaEE context) that aunthenticates to a remote realm and then call a secured remote EJB deployed in Glassfish 3.1, using Programmatic Login.

Does any one knows a good tutorial and/or sample codes of an app like this? I have found some links related to call remote EJB but without the aunthenticacion part, or within a servlet.. which is not my case

greetings

Comment: You could try perusing http://webdev.apl.jhu.edu/~jcs/ejava-javaee/ project files and looking around. I'm not quite sure what the major difference between Glassfish vs Tomcat would be in an overall context, but the examples are excellent.

Comment: thank you Compass for your answer. I'll look there ;)